# Same Python code returns different results for same input string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below code is supposed to return the most common letter in the TEXT string in the format:

- always lowercase
- ignoring punctuation and spaces
- in the case of words such as "One" - where there is no 2 letters the same - return the first letter in the alphabet

Each time I run the code using the same string, e.g. "One" the result cycles through the letters...weirdly though, only from the third try (in this "One" example).

```
text=input('Insert String: ')
def mwl(text):
    from string import punctuation
    from collections import Counter
    for l in punctuation:
        if l in text:
            text = text.replace(l,'')
    text = text.lower()
    text=''.join(text.split())
    text= sorted(text)
    collist=Counter(text).most_common(1)
    print(collist[0][0])
mwl(text)
```

Comment: Can you show a sample input? along with the expected output and the result that you actually get when you run this code.

Comment: I don't think the values in `Counter` are sorted, even if you give it sorted input.

Comment: @Pankaj e.g. "One" returns "o", then "o" again, then "e" and then "n". Should always be "e". Everyone is correct on Counter using dictionary, how should I sort then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be done without `Counter` or `OrderedDict`:

```
In [1]: s = 'Find the most common letter in THIS sentence!'
In [2]: letters = [letter.lower() for letter in s if letter.isalpha()]
In [3]: max(set(letters), key=letters.count)
Out[3]: 'e'
```

Answer (score 10):

`Counter` uses a dictionary:

```
>>> Counter('one')
Counter({'e': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1})
```

Dictionaries are not ordered, hence the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the desired output with `OrderedDict` replacing the below two lines:

```
text= sorted(text)
collist=Counter(text).most_common(1)
```

with:

```
collist = OrderedDict([(i,text.count(i)) for i in text])
collist = sorted(collist.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

You also need to import `OrderedDict` for this.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
>>> text = 'One'
>>> collist = OrderedDict([(i,text.count(i)) for i in text])
>>> print(sorted(collist.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[0][0])
O  
>>> print(sorted(collist.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[0][0])
O    # it will always return O
>>> text = 'hello'
>>> collist = OrderedDict([(i,text.count(i)) for i in text])
>>> print(sorted(collist.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[0][0])
l    # l returned because it is most frequent
```

Comment: Txs used your suggestion, did some research, and modified between key sort and value sort depending on my need - it worked. The best and easiest solution, which worked was from @xnx. txs